# Generating a file path with double quotes in XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have an XML in the form

```
<root>
<image> C:/images/image1.jpg </image>
</root>
```

Now i need to use this path (C:/images/image1.jpg) in my XSL-FO in such a way that it looks like,

```
<fo:external-graphic src="C:/images/image1.jpg" />
```

How i can achieve that in my XSL-FO using the path from XML??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="image">
  <fo:external-graphic src="{normalize-space()}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think your example might be missing something then. Tomalek's code produces the output shown.